# WordPress/woocommerce : Add dropdown choice (where did you find us?) on checkout + create a dashboard with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm a PHP/JS novice, and love to learn more about coding. Today I need your help (pretty please!)

I'm currently trying to add a dropdown option on a Woocommerce checkout so visitors can say where they found us.
So I used a snippet a programmer already coded and tweaked it a little bit.
The only think quite different between my website and his was that he used Polylang and I'm not (unilingual website).

Everything works except the admin dashboard doesn't display the right info : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNQse.png

In my orders, I expect to have just one entry (1x "Bouche à oreille"). Not that.

Here what I did to have this result :

**FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
    /**

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'kantaloup_admin_enqueue');
function kantaloup_admin_enqueue()
{
    //wp_enqueue_style('kantaloup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('chart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/Chart.bundle.min.js');

}

 function get_order_references_fields($return = '')
{
    if($return == 'keys'){
        return array(
            ('Bouche à oreille'),
            ('Médias sociaux'),
            ('Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)'),
            ('Livre/Magazine'),
            ('Partenaire'),
            ('Autre'),
        );
    }

    return array(
        ('Bouche à oreille') => 'Bouche à oreille',
        ('Médias sociaux') => 'Médias sociaux',
        ('Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)') => 'Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)',
        ('Livre/Magazine') => 'Livre/Magazine',
        ('Partenaire') => 'Partenaire',
        ('Autre') => 'Autre',
    );
}


/*
 * Checkout fields: Add
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_fields_at_checkout');
function custom_fields_at_checkout($fields)
{

    $fields['billing']['referred_by'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?'),
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('referred-by-checkout-field-input form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => get_order_references_fields()
    );

    return $fields;

}

/*
 * Checkout fields: Validate
 */
/*
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_validate');
function custom_fields_at_checkout_validate()
{
    if(! $_POST['referred-by']){
        wc_add_notice(__('Veuillez remplir le champ «Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?»'), 'error');
    }
}
*/

/*
 * Checkout fields: Add to order meta
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_meta');
function custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_meta($order_id)
{
    if(! empty($_POST['referred_by']) )
    {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'referred_by', sanitize_text_field($_POST['referred_by']) );
    }
}

/*
 * Checkout fields: Add to order admin page
 */
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_admin_page', 10, 1);
function custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_admin_page($order)
{
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?') . ' :</strong><br>' . get_post_meta($order->id, 'refered_by', true) . '</p>';
}

/*
 * Add admin page for support tab
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_order_report_admin_menu');
function create_order_report_admin_menu()
{
    $title = "Rapport de références";
    add_menu_page($title, $title, 'manage_options', 'sales-type-report', 'sales_type_report', '', '3.1');

    function sales_type_report()
    {
        include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/admin/sales-report.php');
    }
}

/*
 * Get order references and return json object
 */
function get_order_references_json()
{
    $references = get_order_references_fields();

    /*
     * Build the labels
     */
    $the_labels = [];
    foreach($references as $slug => $label)
    {
        $the_labels[] = $label;
    }

    /*
     * Build the datasets
     */
    $the_datasets = [];
    $this_dataset = new stdClass();

    $this_dataset->label = ['Nombre de commandes'];
    $this_dataset->backgroundColor = ['#CFF09E', '#A8DBA8', '#79BD9A', '#3B8686', '#0B486B', '#1B6995', '#1E81B9', '#88AABD'];
    $this_dataset->borderColor = ['#CFF09E', '#A8DBA8', '#79BD9A', '#3B8686', '#0B486B', '#1B6995', '#1E81B9', '#88AABD'];
    $this_dataset->borderWidth = 2;

    $orders = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'closed, wc-on-hold'
        )
    );

    if( empty($orders) ) return;

    $the_datasets_bars = [];
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $reference_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'referred_by', true);

        if(! empty($reference_meta) ){

            foreach($references as $slug => $label)
            {
                if($slug == $reference_meta){
                    $the_datasets_bars[$slug] = ! isset($the_datasets_bars[$slug]) ? 0 : ++$the_datasets_bars[$slug];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $correct_order = get_order_references_fields('keys');
    $correctly_ordered_dataset_bars = array_merge(array_flip($correct_order), $the_datasets_bars);

    $this_dataset->data = array_values($correctly_ordered_dataset_bars);

    $the_datasets[] = $this_dataset;

    /*
     * Build the final array
     */
    $data = array(
        'labels' => $the_labels,
        'datasets' => $the_datasets
    );

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

**In includes/admin/sales-report.php :**

```
<style>
    .sep{
        margin:40px 0;
    }
    .excerpt:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    .excerpt img{
        display:block;
        margin: 30px 0;
        max-width: 1024px;
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .top{
        float:right;
    }
    ol ol{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var ctx = $('#the-sales-references-table');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: <?= get_order_references_json(); ?>,
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>

<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Rapport des références sur les commandes</h1>

    <div class="wrap">
        <canvas id="the-sales-references-table"></canvas>
    </div>

    <? get_order_references_json(); ?>
</div>
```

I also added chart.js in child theme (this part is working).
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: in which variable you don't have the expected value ?

Comment: The charts itself don't have the right values. Check on my screenshot : https://i.imgur.com/JYLmTaz.png
It should normall be one entry (1x "Bouche à oreille").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking and testing your code, here are a few points that caused the issue you identify in the screenshot.

1. The array of data passed to the Chart was empty, which is why you have this "stair"-like pattern. It seems to be how ChartJS.org displays data when it's empty (maybe it defaults to some internal data).
2. The data were empty because it is not possible to pass a PHP function directly in the JavaScript (`data: <?= get_order_references_json(); ?>`). By testing it in the browser, the 'data' variable was empty and caused an error. Instead, what I did is to use WordPress's `wp_localize_script` to run the function beforehand in PHP and then pass the `json_encoded` data as a JS variable. Using that approach, it's possible to then `JSON.parse` the JS variable directly in the `data` variable. If more data was in play, it would be best to use AJAX requests to dedicated PHP functions.
3. Even if the data were not empty, you would still get the "stair"-like pattern because if only a few of the 'references' were present, the others would be empty and thus cause the "stair"-like pattern. To fix that, I prefill the array with zeroes (0s) in all slots before assigning them. `$the_datasets_bars = array_fill_keys(array_keys($references), 0);` This works.
4. There were a few minor issues I fixed that prevented the code from running in my test WP environment.

Here's the modified code with comments in ALL CAPS:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Description: Custom features.
 * Version: 2019.1.0.0
 */

 /*
 * kantaloup enqueue
 */
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'kantaloup_admin_enqueue');
function kantaloup_admin_enqueue()
{
    //wp_enqueue_style('kantaloup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('chart', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/Chart.bundle.min.js');

    // FIX: need to pass the data to the client-side so they can be accessible via JS
    wp_localize_script('chart', 'test', array(
        'data' => get_order_references_json()
    ));
}

function get_order_references_fields($return = '')
{
    if($return == 'keys'){
        return array(
            ('Bouche à oreille'),
            ('Médias sociaux'),
            ('Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)'),
            ('Livre/Magazine'),
            ('Partenaire'),
            ('Autre'),
        );
    }

    return array(
        ('Bouche à oreille') => 'Bouche à oreille',
        ('Médias sociaux') => 'Médias sociaux',
        ('Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)') => 'Moteurs de recherche (Google, Bing...)',
        ('Livre/Magazine') => 'Livre/Magazine',
        ('Partenaire') => 'Partenaire',
        ('Autre') => 'Autre',
    );
}


/*
 * Checkout fields: Add
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_fields_at_checkout');
function custom_fields_at_checkout($fields)
{

    $fields['billing']['referred_by'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?'),
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('referred-by-checkout-field-input form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true,
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => get_order_references_fields()
    );

    return $fields;

}

/*
 * Checkout fields: Validate
 */
/*
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_validate');
function custom_fields_at_checkout_validate()
{
    if(! $_POST['referred-by']){
        wc_add_notice(__('Veuillez remplir le champ «Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?»'), 'error');
    }
}
*/

/*
 * Checkout fields: Add to order meta
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_meta');
function custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_meta($order_id)
{
    if(! empty($_POST['referred_by']) )
    {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'referred_by', sanitize_text_field($_POST['referred_by']) );
    }
}

/*
 * Checkout fields: Add to order admin page
 */
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_admin_page', 10, 1);
function custom_fields_at_checkout_add_to_order_admin_page($order)
{
    // FIX: there was an error accessing $order->id; need to use the get_id() 
    echo '<p><strong>' . __('Où nous avez-vous entendu parler de nous?') . ' :</strong><br>' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'referred_by', true) . '</p>';
}

/*
 * Add admin page for support tab
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'create_order_report_admin_menu');
function create_order_report_admin_menu()
{
    $title = "Rapport de références";
    add_menu_page($title, $title, 'manage_options', 'sales-type-report', 'sales_type_report', '', '3.1');
}
// FIX: separated the function to be outside of the above function
function sales_type_report()
{
    include('includes/admin/sales-report.php');
}

/*
 * Get order references and return json object
 */
function get_order_references_json()
{
    $references = get_order_references_fields();

    /*
     * Build the labels
     */
    $the_labels = [];
    foreach($references as $slug => $label)
    {
        $the_labels[] = $label;
    }

    /*
     * Build the datasets
     */
    $the_datasets = [];
    $this_dataset = new stdClass();

    $this_dataset->label = ['Nombre de commandes'];
    $this_dataset->backgroundColor = ['#CFF09E', '#A8DBA8', '#79BD9A', '#3B8686', '#0B486B', '#1B6995', '#1E81B9', '#88AABD'];
    $this_dataset->borderColor = ['#CFF09E', '#A8DBA8', '#79BD9A', '#3B8686', '#0B486B', '#1B6995', '#1E81B9', '#88AABD'];
    $this_dataset->borderWidth = 2;

    $orders = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'shop_order',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // required to allow >5 results
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
        )
    );

    // print_r($orders);

    if( empty($orders) ) return;

    // FIX: (fill in all keys; otherwise, we get the stair effect)
    $the_datasets_bars = array_fill_keys(array_keys($references), 0);

    foreach($orders as $order){
        // FIX: MUST be $order->ID (Post->ID), not 'id'
        $reference_meta = get_post_meta($order->ID, 'referred_by', true);
        echo $reference_meta . "\n";

        if(! empty($reference_meta) ){

            foreach($references as $slug => $label)
            {
                if($slug == $reference_meta){
                    $the_datasets_bars[$slug] = ! isset($the_datasets_bars[$slug]) ? 0 : ++$the_datasets_bars[$slug];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // FIX: some debug logs
    echo "THE_DATASETS_BARS\n";
    print_r($the_datasets_bars);
    echo "\n";

    $correct_order = get_order_references_fields('keys');
    $correctly_ordered_dataset_bars = array_merge(array_flip($correct_order), $the_datasets_bars);

    $this_dataset->data = array_values($correctly_ordered_dataset_bars);

    $the_datasets[] = $this_dataset;

    /*
     * Build the final array
     */
    $data = array(
        'labels' => $the_labels,
        'datasets' => $the_datasets
    );

    // FIX: added JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE; otherwise, French accents are mishandled
    return json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
```

**includes/admin/sales-report.php**

```
<style>
    .sep{
        margin:40px 0;
    }
    .excerpt:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    .excerpt img{
        display:block;
        margin: 30px 0;
        max-width: 1024px;
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    .top{
        float:right;
    }
    ol ol{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script>
    let $ = jQuery
    // FIX: the way this method was launched caused problems when loading in browser;
    // there were nested 'document.ready' functions
    $(function() {
        console.warn("data", test);

        var ctx = $('#the-sales-references-table');
        console.info(ctx);
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx[0].getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'bar',
            // FIX: parse data from the PHP-generated JS data variable
            data: JSON.parse(test.data),
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<div class="wrap">
    <h1>Rapport des références sur les commandes</h1>

    <div class="wrap">
        <canvas id="the-sales-references-table"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- FIX (remove the PHP function) -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!